# cudaMemcpyFromSymbol and cudaMemcpyToSymbol always return cudaErrorInvalidSymbol (13) error

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a problem with call cudaMemcpyFrom(To)Symbol function in CUDA C++ API. Alternative ideas with storing some parameters between blocks are welcome. Below I've provide some (example) code, that doesn't work correctly.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int avgHost(int*, int);

cudaError_t cudaError;

__device__ int getGlobalIdx()
{
    int blockId = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z;
    int threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z) + (threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y)) + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    return threadId;
}

__device__ int avg;
__device__ int count;
__device__ int sum;

__global__ void avgKernel(const int *arr)
{
    auto idx = getGlobalIdx();
    count++;
    sum += arr[idx];
    avg = sum / count;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const int arraySize = 128;
    auto arr1 = (int*)__vcrt_malloc_normal(arraySize * sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    auto hostAvg = avgHost(arr1, arraySize);
    fprintf_s(stdout, "AVG: %d", hostAvg);
    free(arr1);
    return 0;
}

int avgHost(int* arr, int arraySize)
{
    int *dArray = nullptr;
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaError = cudaMemcpyToSymbol((void *)count, (void*)0, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaError)
    {
        fprintf_s(stderr, "%s\t%d\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaError), __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dArray, arraySize * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dArray, arr, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    avgKernel <<<1, arraySize>>> (dArray);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int hostResult = -1;
    cudaError = cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hostResult, (void *)avg, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaError)
    {
        fprintf_s(stderr, "%s\t%d\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaError), __LINE__);
    }
    cudaFree(dArray);
    return hostResult;
}
```

When I launch code system printed

```
invalid device symbol   55 AVG: -1

C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\CudaTests\x64\Debug\cudabase.exe
(process 18152) exited with code 0.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The symbol arguments are wrong. Just pass them. Don't cast them.

Comment: @talonmies If I simply pass I've got en syntax error "Argument of type int is not incompatible with type const void *".

Comment: No you don't. You get an intellisense error. The code will compile if you try it

Comment: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/R3ihqS  for reference (note I changed the non-standard malloc and printf)

Comment: @talonmies TNX!!!

Comment: Please add a short answer describing your solution for the next person with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Remove this lines, because device variable "count" is always 0 before launch kernel.

```
cudaError = cudaMemcpyToSymbol((void *)count, (void*)0, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaError)
    {
        fprintf_s(stderr, "%s\t%d\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaError), __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
```

***EDIT***

```
cudaError = cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hostResult, (void *)avg, sizeof(int), 0, CudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

***TO***

```
cudaError = cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hostResult, avg, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

(remove cast from parameter "avg"). Intellisence provide error, but code compile and run success.